# Java Serialization Exception Message

Tags: java, spring, serialization, tomcat, servlets

When running an application locally on my box, the application works perfectly. When deployed to QA, the error below is received. I am running Tomcat 5.5.23 locally and in QA. The application also uses Spring MVC.

> ERROR 2011-03-01 16:41:42: Exception loading sessions from persistent storagejava.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.everbank.uft.entities.ldc.VoidReason
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1333)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1402)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:931)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:432)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.everbank.uft.entities.ldc.VoidReason
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:948)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:517)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4363)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1180)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1151)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:313)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
>       ... 6 more
>   ERROR 2011-03-01 16:42:49: UserTrackingFilter.doFilter() failed. message:Servlet execution threw an exceptionjavax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>       at com.everbank.uft.filters.UserTrackingFilter.doFilter(UserTrackingFilter.java:65)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>       at com.everbank.uft.filters.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:36)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:870)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Need more info..   How are you deploying to "QA" ?  How do the environments differ ?   From the stack trace the error originates from Hibernate so there may be an bug in the app where an entity is being accessed over a network ?  Hibernate requires entities to be Serializable to send stuff across a network boundary.  Suggest 'com.everbank.uft.entities.ldc.VoidReason ' needs to be serializable.

Comment: @dionysus how to solve this issue. i am also getting when deployed into tomcat 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means you have put an object in the session that is not serializable, and you have enabled session persistence on server stop.

You have multiple options:

- make the class in question implement `Serializable`
- remove it from the session on `sessionDestroyed(..)` of a `HttpSessionListener`
- if it is a member of another class stored in the session, make it `transient`
- simply ignore the error

You should also clean the "work" directory of tomcat so that no previous serialized session is restored.

Comment: Thanks!! Making the VoidReason class Serializable helped.

Answer (score 2):

com.everbank.uft.entities.ldc.VoidReason is not Serializable, it does not implement Serializable or inherit from something that does.

Answer (score 0):

Could there be serialized Tomcat sessions on your QA server that are damaged or otherwise jacked up?

Try deleting: ${catalina.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/"whatever your app name is"/SESSION.ser

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly the SESSION.ser file contains?

Comment: It contains session state, if you have Restart Persistence enabled. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/manager.html (under Standard Manager Implementation)